# starting express project from powershell

Tags: powershell, express, express-generator

We start an express project created by using the [NPM express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) on Windows by running:

```
set debug=project-name:* & npm start
```

What is the equivalent command in Windows PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Powershell has different way to set the environment variable and to chain the commands. You can use the command:

```
$env:debug = "project-name:*"; npm start
```

**Add:**

In order to verify whether the variable is set or not, you can use the command:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:debug
```

The output will be,

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
debug                          project-name:*
```

Comment: Your answer is working perfectly. I got the server running ok. But the value of the variable debug is not being displayed. I got the following error:                                
 PS F:\MyData\Web\express\wdwnae\meadowlark\site> Get-ChildItem Env:debug
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'debug' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem Env:debug
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (debug:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Thanks but the second part of your answer is giving error.